Why is this closure running prematurely?
A while ago I found this answer by Shepmaster about how to implement cleanup code at the end of a Rust test. I added my own "generalised" idea from his, here.
It's been running fine as intended... until today. All of a sudden, for reasons I don't understand, the drop() method is running too early:
#[test]
fn excluded_patterns_stop_parts_of_directory_tree_from_being_indexed() -> Result<()> {
    let dir = env::temp_dir();
    let delivered_temp_dir_path = dir.as_path();
    let temp_rust_testing_dir_path = delivered_temp_dir_path.join("rust_testing");
    let cleanup_dir_path = temp_rust_testing_dir_path.clone();
    let cleanup_dir_path_str = cleanup_dir_path.to_str().ok_or_else(|| {
        anyhow!(
            "temp dir path cant be converted to str: |{:?}|",
            cleanup_dir_path
        )
    })?;
    println!(">>>>>>>>> About to create Noisy... ");
    let _ = Noisy::new(&|| -> Result<()> {
        println!(">>>>>>>>> Noisy drop running");
        Ok(std::fs::remove_dir_all(cleanup_dir_path_str)?)
    });
    println!(">>>>>>>>> ... Noisy created ");
    //…
}

... now, before "Noisy created" I'm getting "Noisy drop running" and the test fails, with the reasonable message "Noisy drop nasty: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)". This is reasonable because the temporary directory from env::temp_dir() is not created by Rust: you have to std::fs::create_dir_all(...) yourself. So remove_dir_all(...) is naturally unable to find the directory in question and returns Err.
Can anyone suggest an explanation of why this closure is being run before the code gets to the "Noisy create" line?
I've tried lots of permutations, I've tried commenting out other tests, and I've tried nextest instead of test.
I might also mention that yesterday another strange instability started cropping up on my system, with nextest failing intermittently to run all my tests for no discernible reason, as described in this question. (I have now added an issue for this at nextest's Github site).
I wondered whether this could perhaps be due to insufficient memory or something in my system. But I've closed down a few memory-hungry things and don't believe this can be the explanation.
Could these 2 problems I'm experiencing be related in some way?

Thanks. First mystery is that I've been using _ for some weeks and that problem hasn't cropped up! Secondly, when I change to _noisy I get a compile error: "creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use". I suppose that merits a new question (after I've tried to understand the issue...).

&|| -> Result…  creates a reference to the temporary closure, which is immediately dropped at the end of the statement, remove the & (and possibly change Noisy(&impl Fn()) to Noisy(impl Fn())

Yes, thanks. So kind of strange that it hasn't complained until now?

Its not a problem with let _ because then Noisy is dropped at the end of the statement as well, before the closure.
